# Java Text Area not posting

Tags: java, servlets, textarea

The text area value I am trying to submit is around 400 chars and the value the servlet gets is null. When I limit this down to less that 75 chars the servlet will get the proper value. 
Has anyone seen this happen before?

JSP

```
<form action="/admin/homepageupdates">
   <div class="body">
      <textarea name="txtcontent" rows="7" cols="105"><%=hp.getBodyText()%></textarea>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Servlet

```
String textbody = (String)request.getParameter("txtcontent");
```

Comment: Without any actual Java code, and without the <form> that submits the textarea, there's no way to even begin to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: *Please* format properly using the code (1010) button. Otherwise nobody can read your question properly!

Answer (score 4):

You must use the `POST` method for any large amount of data (`<form ... method="POST">`) The `GET` method can only transfer a few bytes, depending on how much the browser and the web server allow in an URL.